# Incorrect version of office plugin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, plugins, visual-studio-2013, vsto

I developed an office plugin and in `AssemblyInfo.cs` I specified

```
 [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.3.17")]
 [assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.3.17")]
```

However, after I install my plugin the version under add/remove programs is `1.0.0.0`

So I checked the VSTO file that being create during the build process (which I do with VS2013) and saw that inside the `assemblyIdentity` tag, the version number is `1.0.0.0` (instead of being `1.0.3.17`)..

In order to install the plugin I use the `VSTOInstaller.exe` and pass my VSTO file to it..

So How can I change the version inside the VSTO file? Or in more general sense - Where should I specify the version that will be presented in the Add/Remove section?

Thanks,
Noam

Comment: Try to change the publish version in project properties publish tab.

Comment: @RandRandom if I choose the publish option then yes, it works, however that means I need to change my setup process (stop working with VSTOInstaller and use setup.exe instead) Is there an option to change the version in VSTO file without publishing?

Comment: I dont think you have to use the publish now button, just change the value and upon building the generated vsto file will have that version number.

Comment: Just tested it my self again and it works as expected in the .vsto file the version number is as specified in the publish version. Use notepad to open your .vsto and search for the line ``<assemblyIdentity name="xxxx.vsto" version="1.2.3.4"`` to verify it yourself. (changed it to 1.2.3.4 at my addin)

Comment: @RandRandom you right, it's working, but I need to be able to do it programmatically from the c# code, how can I achieve that?

Comment: The c# code inside the addin itself? You are currently changing the above mentioned assembly infos with c# ``[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.3.17")]``?

Comment: Yes, I do it in the `AssemblyInfo.cs` under `Properties` but it doesn't working, I need to find the equivalent of the publish setting you mentioned inside in code..

Comment: You could probably edit the generated *.vsto and *.manifest files (they're XML) but you'd have to re-sign them afterward which can be a complicated task. You really should not change the version from code though, instead you should change your setup process. By the way, you do not have to go through setup.exe if you use Publish Now, that is only for prerequisites.

Comment: What do you mean IN THE AssemblyInfo.cs, are you actually writing in the file directly before it compiles? If so, I would suggest modifing the project file itself before you build the project. In there you will find the xmlelement ``<ApplicationVersion>1.2.3.4</ApplicationVersion>``

Comment: @RandRandom Ok, so where can I find this "poject file" I'm a python developer so not used to visual studio and c# projects in general, thanks

Comment: Since its a C# project there should be a *.csproj file, next to your other files.

Comment: @RandRandom thanks I found it and can see the <ApplicationVersion> tag, but I need to change it from code (not manually) how can I access the "applicationVersion" tag from code?

Comment: Just to clarify, we are talking about code - outside the office plugin - that will run before you compile the project? It is no code that will run inside the office plugin and you think about changing this value at runtime?

Comment: @RandRandom No. we are talking about code - INSIDE the office plugin - that will run DURING compile time, so NO change in runtime. I'm sorry if I wasn't clear, English isn't my favorite.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157864/discussion-between-noam-and-rand-random).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the version number the `VSTOIntaller.exe` uses, you have to change the `Publish Version` in the project properties page.

To get there `Right Click` on your `Project` go to `Properties` and select the `Publish` Tab on the left side, there you will find the `Public Version`.

You don't have to publish the project, the build process will pick up that information and write it into the generated `.vsto` file.

In the `.vsto` you can find the `XmlElement` `AssemblyIdentity` as an example:

```
<assemblyIdentity name="xxxx.vsto" version="1.2.3.4"
```

You can also find that information in the project file (`*.csproj` for C#), there you will find an `XmlElement` `ApplicationVersion` as an example:

```
<ApplicationVersion>1.2.3.4</ApplicationVersion>
```

To change this information by code as the OP wants I suggested to ask a new question, as his intends are to modify it during the build process and I only could think of ways to do it either before or after the build.

For example to change it before the build outside of the actual plugin, you could use the following:

```
var file = @"xxxx.csproj";
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(file);
var ns = xDoc.Root.Name.Namespace;
xDoc.Element(ns + "Project")
    .Element(ns + "PropertyGroup")
    .Element(ns + "ApplicationVersion").Value = "1.2.3.5";

xDoc.Save(file);
```